# Bluetooth,Nvidia graphics card and Wireless connection not working in ASUS x53s

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, nvidia, bluetooth

10 on ASUS X53SC. The Bluetooth and wireless are working on Windows 7 but not in Ubuntu.

I am having NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 520MX, and BLUETOOTH 3.0. Please help me.

While typing `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 520MX] (rev a1)

03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)

04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller

05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: We need information regarding what type of Nvidia card you have, Wireless card you have and Bluetooth card you have. Without that you question is immune to our psychic powers ^^.

Comment: i am having NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 520MX, and BLUETOOTH 3.0. Please help me...

Comment: For the Video card see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/driver-to-use-when-installing-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card?rq=1 For the bluetooth I would need the output of "lshw" or "lspci". If you could add that you might get more help related to this.